# Who wins if player who said 'cabo' has lowest points but another player also has the same?

Tags: untagged

Game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_%28game%29

More reference link: https://www.wired.com/2011/01/pass-the-time-with-cabo-where-strategy-meets-quirky-fun/

We were playing this using playing cards, but logic remains same.

One action in the game play is,

Call “Cabo”, which states - If a player thinks that they have the lowest scoring hand, they can call “Cabo” to end the round. There is a penalty for performing this action if you do not actually have the lowest hand.

Now, we had a situation where 3 players (A, B, C) were in the game, and Player A called 'cabo'. Now at the end of the round, hands were as below

A: Ace (one)

B: Ace (one)

C: Queen (Twelve)

Now, C is clearly higher whereas A and B are tied. Now, does this qualify as lowest hand for player A who called the 'cabo' as he is technically having the lowest which happens to be tied with another player? Who wins that round? Does player A, gets the advantage of calling cabo?

Answer (score 1):

Having looked around a bit I have not seen any rules for dealing with ties but there are two ways to handle it and personally I think the first is the best since there is some risk involved in calling cabo.

First: The player that called cabo wins as it can be risky to call it since the other players all get one more turn to play as stated in the wiki.

> When a player calls cabo, the other players each get one more turn and then everyone has to turn their hidden cards face-up, and lay down the cards from their hand. The player with the lowest score wins

Second: You declare it a tie and all players with the low score share the win.

Answer (score 0):

The Wired article you link has some more details

> Games of Cabo are played over the course of several rounds where
>   players will try to minimize the value of their 4-card hand. 
>   Following each round, the losers will receive penalty points based on
>   the cards left in their hands. Once a player hits 100 penalty points,
>   the player with the lowest score wins the game.
>
> There’s also some opportunity to “shoot the moon”.  Any player who
>   ends a round with two 12s and both 13s (a very risky feat) will
>   receive 0 points while all other players receive 50. Also, if the
>   player who causes the game to ends can finish with exactly 100 points,
>   their score will be reduced to 50 points.

So there isn't a winner declared for an individual round. The final winner is based on total score. There aren't any tiebreak rules, so I expect multiple people with the lowest total score at the end would be considered tied winners.

Comment: Other sources show that the "winner" of a round is the player with the lowest sum of card values in hand. They receive zero points for the round.

Comment: Yes, mostly I wanted clarity on how to decide a tie breaker for that round. What will  be the difference in points awarded to the player who called 'cabo' and the player who didn't and both have same set of cards at the end.